# KML with Gauß-Krüger-Koordinatensystem

Tags: kml

I need an kml example with https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9F-Kr%C3%BCger-Koordinatensystem coordinates.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Keyhole Markup Language (KML) is defined by the WGS 84 coordinate system.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language

The best way of getting it in Gauss-Kruger CRS is by loading this layer in QGIS and reprojecting it.